# View zoom image when mouse over on thumbnail

Tags: javascript

This is for view zoom image when mouse over on thumbnail. IT'S WORKS !!!

**1. Code for html (smarty)**

```
 <{html_image onmouseout="view_zoom(this, '');" onmouseover="view_zoom(this, this.src);" file=$img}>
```

**2. Code for js :**

```
function view_zoom(o, i)
{
    if(i!=''&&i.indexOf('noimage.jpg') == -1)
    {   
    var s = i.replace('small','big'); 
    var aTag = o;
    var leftpos = toppos = 0;
    do {aTag = aTag.offsetParent; leftpos   += aTag.offsetLeft; toppos += aTag.offsetTop;
    } while(aTag.offsetParent != null);
    var X = o.offsetLeft + leftpos + 100;
    var Y = o.offsetTop + toppos - 20;
    document.getElementById('big_zoom').style.left = X + 'px';
    document.getElementById('big_zoom').style.top = Y + 'px';
    document.getElementById('big_zoom').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('big_zoom').innerHTML='<img src="'+s+'" onload="if(this.width<200) {$(\'big_zoom\').style.display = \'none\');}else if(this.width>300){this.width=300;}$(\'big_zoom\').style.width=this.width+\'px\';"/>'
     } else {
        document.getElementById('big_zoom').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

**3. code for css :**

```
.big_zoom {width:200px;z-index:1000;position:absolute;padding:5px; background:#FFFFFF;}
.big_zoom img{border:#AACCEE 1px solid;padding:5px;}
```

don't forget to add this line in html

```
<div class="big_zoom" id="big_zoom" style="display:none;"></div>
```

lol !!!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work in hosting? Your information is a bit sparse.

Comment: Define "working" and "not working."  What does the code *do*?  In what specific way does it *fail*?  When you debug this, what information can you find?

Comment: working it means tested on PC Locally and not Work in CPANEL

Comment: My guess is that your image is a file location on your hard drive, and not accessible by the same path as a URL.

Comment: i'm sorry guys. i'm forget to add class for big_zoom on HTML. Now IT'S WORKS !!!